# How to visualize content of RRD file

Tags: python, rrdtool

I have a rrd file that i have created using python + rrdtool lib.

How can i look at the content of this file ? is there any way other then fetching data from rrdtool API?

Is there any RRD editor ?

I have recently started using this kind of file, so i am not sure how to visualize it.

Thanks in advance for your Help.
Sumit Purohit

Comment: Have you tried googling for "RRD editor" ? Because I googled one and found 1 editor in a grand total of 5 seconds

Comment: Thanks for your "constructive" reply, meanwhile i figured rrdtool has a function  rrdtool.graph which takes a png file as one of its argument and can generate an image. http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdgraph.en.html

Comment: one more way is to use `rrdtool dump <rrd filename>`          [refer this for more info](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrddump.en.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rrdtool info <file.rrd>` will give you an overview of what is in the file and `rrdtool dump <file.rrd>` will give you the whole content in xml format.